CIDR notation for two specific IP addresses
I have the following IP addresses that I need to set that are allowed to connect to our system:
172.22.254.67
172.22.254.68
I know I could code 172.22.254.67/32 and 172.22.254.68/32 and the /32 means the exact IP, but the field I have won't allow this many characters to be entered on the line.
If I code 172.22.254.0/24 that would allow too many IP's to connect. CIDR is confusing.
I don't know if I could code this 172.22.254.67/2 to allow both IP's to connect.

If you cannot put in 172.22.254.67/32 or 172.22.254.67, then you will have to take it up with whoever is responsible for the software which bars it.

Consider that when the input is limited and you can't fit 172.22.254.67/32 as an authorised source then most likely the application won't interpret CIDR notation correctly anyway. It may  only accept one specific IP-address and then entering 172.22.254.67 might be always interpreted correctly as "this specific IP-address". - For example in Apache the old syntax was to use four octets to block/allow a specific IP-address and to block/allow  the range 172.22.254.0 - 172.22.254.255  you could use only the first three octets 172.22.254  instead of the CIDR notation  172.22.254.0/24

172.22.254.64/29 is the smallest that accommodates both those IPs, but it would still allow more than you want, so you're going to have to just use two /32 entries.
To understand why, look at the numbers in binary:
66 is 01000010
67 is 01000011
68 is 01000100
69 is 01000101

So you need to have 3 bits free to tell 67 and 68 apart from their neighbours. 172.22.254.67/31 would include .66 and .67; 172.22.254.68/31 would include .68 and .69.
